# How does the get_or_create function in Django return two values?

Tags: python, django

I have used the `get_or_create` function on my models in Django. This function returns two values. One is the object itself and the other a boolean flag that indicates whether an existing object was retrieved or a new one created.

Normally, a function can return a single value or a collection of values like a `tuple`, `list` or a dictionary.

How does a function like `get_or_create` return two values?

Comment: It returns a tuple actually..

Comment: it return a tuple with two element on it `return (is_exit, object)`

Comment: Try this: `a = 1, 2; print type(a)`. It is a tuple indeed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`get_or_create()` simply returns a tuple of the two values.  You can then use [sequence unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) to bind the two tuple entries to two names, like in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) example:

```
p, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
    first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)})
```

Answer (score 6):

It returns a tuple. It sounds like you knew that functions could do this, just not that you could assign the results directly to two variables!

See the Django documentation for [`get_or_create`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
# Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved 
# or created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new 
# object was created.

obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
                  defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)})
```

Answer (score 4):

Using tuples/tuple unpacking is often considered as a [quite "pythonic" way](http://faassen.n--tree.net/blog/view/weblog/2005/08/06/0) of returning more than one value.